# how to alternate one test with test suite in pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I am working with researchers who are running a steadily growing test suite, and occasionally they are breaking the tests by having code which damages the environment by modifying something in a way that works when you run a single test but fails in the entire test suite.

What I've built before (in Java) is a test runner which alternates a given test with each test in the test run. This seems like it should be relatively easy in pytest, but figuring out the details has eluded me so far. Anything obvious I'm missing?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by alternating tests? On the other hand, if your tests are implemented in a way that they fail when run with other tests but pass when they are run individually, there seems to be an issues with dependencies between your tests. I would rather fix this by implementing fixtures

Comment: it's a problem with a single test interfering with other tests; the problem needs to be found and fixed. Finding the problem is the issue - in this case, it is a test writing to a value produced by @lru_cache. There have been others.

Comment: Sounds like you want a Setup, something that runs before each test?

Comment: If a test starts to fail the test suite and you need to find it, it is solved like tracking any other regressions in code: by doing a binary search in the VCS (for example, with `git bisect`), finding the chunk of code that introduced the regression and analyzing it. A CI server that runs tests on a regular basis helps by early alerting on new regressions.

Comment: However, maybe I'm still missing a point here - can you give an example of _a test runner which alternates a given test with each test in the test run_?